# How can I turn the expo into react native without problem?

Tags: react-native, expo

I can't run-ios In the react-native form.
The console says file ios is not available
So I have to get out expo from project

How can I do this?

Comment: It's not a clear question, please add some code example or screenshot or do explain more detail about your problem.

Comment: I want to get out of my own sources without expo and without errors

Comment: please edit your question and add some explanation on it.

Comment: How do you know that expo causes the problem? Anyway, to convert an expo project to a non expo project you need to eject. Search for expo eject. If this doesn't work, then create a new react native project using react-native init and copy your source files to this new project.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You mean you don't get the command 'react-native run-ios' in a project you created with 'expo'?

Comment: Do you run `react-native run-ios`? For Expo, you use `expo start` (install `expo-cli` package globally first).